# ionic-firebase-authentication - no write into real time databae

Tags: ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I 've verify the github code . during sign up the user record not going to write into firebase instaed just autheticate the record to firebase authentication .

Can anyone provide the code which able to write the user record (email , password) into fIREBASE real time DB ?

[image]

[https://github.com/loobj126/ionic5-firebase-authentication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AV1VC.png)

what i trying to achieve beside authentication , system to write user record into real time database as below.
[image: b]

Comment: "Can anyone provide the code which able to write the user record (email , password) into fIREBASE real time DB?" That's not really how Stack Overflow works. There are dozens (probably hundreds) of examples of how to write to the database once a user signs in. I recommend trying to build the relevant code yourself based on those example, and posting back in case you get stuck.

Comment: Frank , if possible can share the link with the example? i tried several articles and stekoverflow link yet mostly are authenticate. They not really write into firebase.